# Not able to get the desired output from the given code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, oop

```
lst = [["hi", "bye"], "hello", "goodbye", [9, 2], 4]
greeting_doubled = []
def f(g):
    return 2*lst
greeting_doubled = map(f,lst)
print(greeting_doubled)
```

Expected :

```
[['hi','bye','hi','bye'], 'hellohello', 'goodbyegoodbye',[9,2,9,2], 8]
```

Comment: Please format your code, you can check the formatting rules [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

You had 2 issues with your code

1. in function `f(g)` you were returning `2*lst` rather than `2*g`
2. [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns a generator so to convert to list you have to use `list(generator..)`

**Updated Code:**

```
lst = [["hi", "bye"], "hello", "goodbye", [9, 2], 4]
def f(g):
    return 2*g
getting_doubled = list(map(f,lst))
print(getting_doubled)
```

**Output:**

```
[['hi', 'bye', 'hi', 'bye'], 'hellohello', 'goodbyegoodbye', [9, 2, 9, 2], 8]
```